ChartJS / react-chartjs-2 add horizontal reference line to bar chart
I am creating a barchart with ChartJS / react-chartjs-2.
The barchart is displaying allright, nothing special:

I want to add a horizontal line to display the average of the years totals to see how each actor is performing relative to this average. I found two questions on SO:

How to draw Horizontal line on Bar Chart Chartjs

Chart.js - draw horizontal line based on a certain y-value


But they don't use the react-chartjs-2 wrapper. I am building in NextJS. My understanding of the whole thing is not enough to translate that in to react-chartjs-2. Maybe someone knows?
import { Chart as ChartJS } from "chart.js/auto"
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2"
/* just pasting my element here, no need for the whole component */
 <Bar data={data} ref={ref} options={options} />


did you manage to solve

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/santi-chart-forked-lk27xp  something like this? lmk if u need explaination

Thank you! I managed to make it work. Will reverse engineer to understand what is going on but very helpful already. Appreciated!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rt_aw9zxRSI was very helpful

It looks like someone commented with a working solution for you, but just wanted to add that I am doing this currently using this plugin: chartjs-plugin-annotation
You'll have to register the new plugin when instantiating the chart:
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import {
    TimeScale,
    LinearScale,
    CategoryScale,
    Title,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Tooltip,
    Chart,
    Filler,
} from 'chart.js';

import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';

Chart.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    Title,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Tooltip,
    TimeScale,
    Filler,
    annotationPlugin
);

export default Line;

And then its pretty simple config to add the line nice and easy
const options = {
  ...,
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        line1: {
          type: 'line',
          yMin: 60,
          yMax: 60,
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderWidth: 2,
        }
      }
    }
  }
};


thanks, will try it out, looks neat indeed!
